# How can I use okhttp to receive value from php script to android app?

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I am trying to create an android app in which a user enters login details and the data is validated on server ,for server i am using xampp.I want to get the value shown on the php result page in android app and show it to the user using Toast.

```
@Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO: attempt authentication against a network service.

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Problem is in http", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        String result;
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http:192.168.0.102/db.php?username=tkajbaje@gmail.com&password=123456")
                .build();

        Response response = null;
        try {
            response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        result=response.toString();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        // TODO: register the new account here.
        return true;
    }
```

When I run the app it exits unexpectedly,what could be the problem?Apologies if some important information is missing regarding question.

Comment: Just go through this link i have updated the most recent okhttp3
Link --> https://github.com/yash786agg/okhttp3

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly problematic

```
    try {
        response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

You are catching and logging the error but continuing, so response can be null.

There are other issues with the code

- You are creating a new OkHttp instance for each call
- it's unclear if you are actually running this on a background thread
- IIRC Toast.show should be on UI thread, but okhttp calls should be background